# java.lang.Integer.parseInt won't take 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Like the title says I have this code

```
needleColor = Integer.parseInt(mPrefs.getString("color_key", "-1"));
```

that throws `NumberFormatException` stating "0xFFFFFFFF is not a valid integer". This code worked fine up until eclipse crashed and I wound up completely removing eclipse and re-downloading the adk.

Looking at the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html the colors are represented as ints and the value is -1. So it's a valid int...

Comment: Why not just set `needleColor=-1`?

Comment: Why can't you store it as a number instead of a String in the SharedPreferences?

Comment: Ack, I was out of town suddenly.

I wanted the user to be able to choose whatever color he wanted for the needle, but to default to white. 

And for whatever reason, when I try and store anything other than a string I get an `IllegalFormatException` Go figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` doesn't process the `0x` prefix -- it expects you to pass in the bare digits, and the radix.  `Integer.decode` would probably do what you want, though.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks. I probably had `Interger.decode` in my prior code, but the crash and subsequent fixing caused some unfortunate recoding.